# Diagonalization of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have a skew symmetric matrix $$ C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\ a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\ -a_2 & a_1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ and we have the relation $C = U D U^{-1} $, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. What are the values of $U$ and $D$?

NB: Any values of $U$ and $D$ solve my issue. The $a_i$ values can't be changed.

Comment: They aren't unique. As an extreme example, if $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0,$ you can let $U$ be literally any invertible matrix...

Comment: Any value of U and D solve my issue. Values of $a_i$ s cant be changed

Comment: Are $U$ and $D$ allowed to have complex entries? The eigenvalues of  $C$ are $0$ and $\pm i \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}$.

Comment: Yes provided $ U(e^{D})U^{-1} $ should be a real matrix .

Comment: Hello :) we have $(a_2a_3, a_1a_3, a_1a_2) ^T$ is in the kernel of $C$. If $(a_1, a_2, a_3) \neq (0, 0,0) $, then the kernel is one-dimensional.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I answered this question six months ago. No reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the $a_i$ are real then $E=iC$ is Hermitean so $E=VF{V ^{-1}}$ with $V$ unitary and $F$  diagonal with real entries (the eigenvalues of $E$). Generically $V$ and $F$ are unique (up to a phase factor in $V$). Now
    $C=V(-iF)V^{-1}$ so we can take $U=V$ and $D=-iF$. But then $U{e ^D}U ^{-1}$ is not a real matrix. Why do you think it is? And what do you mean with  "Any values of $U$ and $D$ solve my issue "?

Comment: Hi :) $Ue^DU^{-1}$ is a real matrix, because it is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{C^k}{k! }$, but $U$ has non-real entries.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the three eigen values of $C$ are
$$
0,\quad\mp\, i\, \underbrace{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2}}_{\textstyle=:\lambda}\,.
$$
The matrix $U$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_1&-a_1 a_3+i\lambda a_2&-a_1 a_3-i\lambda a_2\\
a_2&-a_2 a_3-i\lambda a_1&-a_2 a_3+i\lambda a_1  \\
a_3&a_1^2 + a_2^2 &  a_1^2 + a_2^2
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$